# How to auto size a row and Column in a specific sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

I have a debug button on a userform. The debug button needs to do 2 things:

Auto Size row 17
Auto size Column X.

I have tryied this:
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("X").EntireColumn.AutoFit
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("17").EntireRow.AutoFit

The sheet is not protected and yet I get Subscript out of range (Error 9).

Comment: Your workbook has no sheet named Sheet2. Also, `17`, not `"17"`. Also, did you mean `Rows` instead of `Columns` in the second line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
to AutoFit EntireRow
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(17).EntireRow.AutoFit
to AutoFit EntireColumn
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(17).EntireColumn.AutoFit
```